# Possible interpretations for a predicate symbol in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

***PART A***

So, given as structure  A :{1,2,3}  and we are studying the languge of the real numbers. We are asked to say how many possible interpretations for the predicate symbol **$<$**. My question is since we are working on real numbers, do we take for granded that symbol **$<$** has arity 2? Or we combine all possible interpretations for $ A $? Meaning possible interpretations for < are: **(those for arity 1)X(those for arity 2)X(those for arity 3)** or simply all the arity 2 combinations for {1,2,3}?

***PART B***

Give the **smallest* interpretation for symbol <. Depending on what we answer above, if arity 2 is granded then i have no clue what smallest 
interpretation means. If we multiply the possible interpretation for arity 1,2,3 in part A then i suppose that smallest interpretation is the one with arity 1 containing ∅ (empty set)???

Comment: You should assume that $<$ is a binary relation (arity 2). [The cardinality of the structure's universe has no bearing on the arity of its relations, so why stop at 3? Relations on $A$ can be 4-ary, 5-ary, ... 17-ary, ... .] **Part B** Again, $<$ is binary. "Smallest" means in terms of set inclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part A**

You should assume that $<$ is a binary relation (arity 2). Otherwise, the question would have been stated in terms of an arbitrary relation symbol such as $R$.

A binary relation on $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$, so the number of possible interpretations of $<$ in $A$ is the number of binary relations on A, which is the number of subsets of $A\times A$. The size of that collection is:
$$
\lvert \mathcal{P}(A\times A)\rvert = 2^{|A\times A|} = 2^{3x3} = 2^9 = 512.
$$

Re your idea that perhaps you should "combine all possible interpretations for [$<$ in] A": The cardinality of the structure's universe has no bearing on the arity of its relations. Why stop at 3? Relations on $A$ can also be 4-ary, 5-ary, ... 17-ary, ... . If you were to "combine all possible interpretations", then there are $\aleph_0$ many.

**Part B (Hint)**

Again, $<$ is binary. "Smallest" means in terms of set inclusion, or — what amounts to the same thing in this case — in terms of cardinality. So: what's the smallest possible interpretation?

Comment: i guess its {1,1}??

Comment: No, no. Why $(1,1)$ and not any of the other 8 alternatives? Even smaller. Don't guess — think :)

Comment: the $\emptyset $  ??

Comment: Well, is $\emptyset$ a binary relation? [Suppose you have a theory with a single binary relation symbol $R$ and the axiom $\forall x \forall y\, \neg R(x,y)$ — that is, $R$ is not true for any $x,y$. What does the interpretation of $R$ have to be, as a set?]

Comment: thanks for trying to help me , but now i am even more confused. From your comment above what comes to mind is either $\emptyset\$ or all the possible pairs? Cauze R is always false

Comment: Work through the confusion. The set of all pairs is true of all pairs, so it would model $\forall x\forall y\, R(x,y)$. But $\emptyset$ is false of all pairs, models $\forall x\forall y\, \neg R(x,y)$. $\emptyset$ is a perfectly good 2-ary relation (it's also a 1-ary, 3-ary, 1729-ary, etc relation). Obviously (yes?) it's the smallest.

Answer (score 2):

The arity of a relational symbol is defined by the language.  So if we're talking about the usual language of real numbers, < is 2-arity, so any interpretation must also be 2-arity.

For "smallest interpretation", I would guess that means the interpretation of < with the lowest cardinality, in which case I think you almost have the answer already.

Comment: No i dont, please answer this addressing an idiot. I dont understand what lowest cardinality means  since we have said that arity 2 is needed. What i understand is that there is no lowest cardinality and no matter what we choose for set{1,2,3} we are always gonna have 2 elements.

Comment: So an interpretation of < is going to be a set of pairs of elements of A.  So what's the smallest possible set of pairs?

Comment: so you mean {1,1} or the $ \emptyset $ ???

Comment: A set of pairs is a set where each element is an ordered pair (a,b).  {1,1} = {1}, is neither an ordered pair nor a set of pairs, but $\emptyset$ can be seen as an empty set of pairs.